# Please convert Eagle Library

Tags: eaglecad, library, h-bridge

I've scoured the internet for an EAGLE library with the SN754410NE part. I found one, but it's for a version previous to 4.11 and I'm on a Mac and have no way to convert it 55.10. The original file is at http://db.tt/66pnv4Y. Can anyone hook me up with a recent version?

Comment: It is relatively easy to design Eagle parts in Eagle. You will probably find it easier to draw them yourself.

Comment: You'll find that you have to create custom parts for almost every project. It's pretty easy once you do it a few times. The first time, just copy a similar part then edit it. When doing production work (yes, many use EAGLE for production work) you may find that it is faster to do create your own footprints and silkscreen symbols rather than double-check the given library.

Comment: "yes, many use EAGLE for production work" - Is using Eagle for production bad? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, make your own footprints.

http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110

Comment: It seems wasteful but de facto. Guess I have no choice :/